# How can I create ZIP64 file and test it?

Tags: zip, archiving

I need a zip file ([ZIP64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#ZIP64)) for a test case, I put a `bigfile` of `5GB` full of zeros  and zipped it, but I don't know if is ZIP64.

Should the ZIP file exceed 4Gb to be ZIP64? A 4Gb file for a test case is pretty twisted can I have another option?

Comment: Are you just after some way to confirm that the zip you create is actually a 64bit instead of a 32bit zip?

Comment: @DaveRook yes but I think they are not called 64bit and 32bit, just orginal zip format and ZIP64.

Comment: Googling matched [this python3 script](https://gist.github.com/gumblex/5573ddb33c21fca4aecf). It worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the DotNetZip devkit from http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/. Extract the `Tools` folder from the dev kit and run `DotNetZip-WinFormsTool.exe`

It has a ZIP64 setting with the options:

- Always
- AsNecessary
- Never

Select the Always option to create archives in the ZIP64 format even if they only contain small files. The interface is a little clunky, but it's workable; it allowed me to create the ZIP64 test cases I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The archival tool 7zip supports zip64 archives. You could use that to generate your test case or validate it.

Comment: http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt - 7-Zip now supports Zip64 extension of ZIP format. So now it's possible to compress files bigger than 4 GB to ZIP archives. - 'zip' is just the container, 'deflate64' is the actual compression scheme used by a zip64 file.

Comment: 7zip supports deflate64 and also zip64.

Comment: I don't find a way to test if a zip64 with 7zip

Comment: I was able to determine if my Zip was Zip64 in 7-Zip by looking at the *Characteristics* column of the zip entries: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb6ZX.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The default `zip`(3.0) command in linux can be used to create a zip64 file. The following command on a sample HelloWorld.docx file stored in the current working directory would create a zip64 file.

```
cat HelloWorld.docx | zip > zip64file.zip
```

Here is the output of running the `file` command on the created file

> zip64file.zip: Zip archive data, at least v4.5 to extract

Comment: How would I know that it's indeed a ZIP64 file that was created? Is the `file` message specific for ZIP64 files?

Comment: @gronostaj The file command is not specific for zip64 files. That can be used on any filetype to determine what it is based on certain signature checks. A zip64 file can be verified by looking at the raw bytes(0x12-0x16). The value would be 0xffffffff. Here is the link to where I got the information from https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html

Comment: As documented on the man page: "Zip64 is also used for archives streamed from standard input as the size of such archives are not known in advance"

Comment: To ensure the `zip64` extensions are added you need to use the `-zf` argument.
As noted here: https://superuser.com/questions/1527547/how-to-create-a-zip-file-openable-with-a-specific-version-or-greater