# How to create a zip file openable with a specific version or greater

Tags: zip

```
$ file *
68bcd5ef-e7a2-471d-a9b9-2c02fdfe9c69.data: Zip archive data, at least v4.5 to extract
70e07136-ba86-47fd-abcf-d502646bf69e.data: Zip archive data, at least v4.5 to extract
75007091-d9d6-4acf-a919-1740425edcc7.data: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

I would like the last file to also be 'Zip archive data, at least v4.5 to extract'.  I created it with zip(1).  How can I make it the same format as the others?

Comment: Unzip and rezip?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Why does the last file bother you?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I have a program that reads from the other zips, but not the one I made.  Step 1 of troubleshooting is to get it into the same zip format (which `file` will ID as 'at least v4.5 to extract')

Comment: IMO the question should be "How to make program Foo open this file?" or so. The *hypothesis* that `v2.0` vs `v4.5` is crucial would be a part of your research effort then. What error message do you get? From what command? What exact command did you use to create the third file? Was it substantially different than commands used to create other files? What does the program do? Will you accept (or at least consider) an alternative? Also note relevant information should be [edit]ed into the question, not posted in comments.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Nope, the question is how to make the files the same type.  My end goal is not the question here - the question could apply to various scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 4.5 of the zip spec adds support for Zip64. Below is from [APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

```
4.4.3.2 Current minimum feature versions are as defined below:

 1.0 - Default value
 1.1 - File is a volume label
 2.0 - File is a folder (directory)
 2.0 - File is compressed using Deflate compression
 2.0 - File is encrypted using traditional PKWARE encryption
 2.1 - File is compressed using Deflate64(tm)
 2.5 - File is compressed using PKWARE DCL Implode 
 2.7 - File is a patch data set 
 4.5 - File uses ZIP64 format extensions
```

If you need to have a zip archive that requires 4.5 to extract you will have to unzip & rezip the 2.0 archive.

You can force `zip` to crate a Zip64 archive by including the command line options `-fz` with the zip command

```
zip -fz files
```